# Excel workbook as database, insert update issue

Tags: vba, excel-2010

There is a excel workbook which is used as a database kept on shared folder. The users have other workbook which has the userform which allows the insert and update into the database.

I am using `connection.Execute` method for insert and Update and use  `recordsaffected` for my confirmation.

Although the `recordsaffected` gives the correct, sometimes insert or update never happens.

What can I do to fix this?

```
Set oCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & shtSetting.Range("filePath").Value & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


strSQL = "Insert Into [Sheet1$] (" & _
"sr_no, process,employee_id,employee_name) Values ( " & _
"'" & sr_no & "','" & process & "','" & emp_id & "','" & emp_name & "')"

oCn.Execute strSQL, r_status
oCn.Close

Set oCn = Nothing
```

Comment: The problem is the "sometimes". You need to investigate when that sometimes is. Is it when multiple users connect? Is it when you insert records? Is it when you append records?

Comment: I tested this as a single user and have faced this issue. sometimes update and sometimes insert doesn't works.

Answer (score -1):

Unless there's a strong reason to store the data in an Excel spreadsheet, though, I'd consider offloading the database management portion of it to an Access database (even if you don't have Access, you can still create an mdb/accdb file). If nothing else, that's going to give you access to indexing, which can improve performance tremendously. You can still mirror the Access data in Excel by using data connections (or other techniques).

If you are stuck with doing everything in Excel, one (potentially slow) solution is to query the sheet once you've performed your update, to confirm that it has made the change that you expect. If you're doing an insert, you may be able to get away with just counting the records, but it's definitely safer to look for the exact value you just inserted.

Also: if the users are making multiple updates, you might want to consider keeping the connection open until the form closes. (Though I don't recall if this causes locking issues with an Excel backend or not. It would generally improve performance in Access.)